# Delete all with exceptions from command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a folder with about 50 different files in it (NAME1.jpg, NAME2.jpg, NAME3.jpg...).

I have a program that runs, and splits each file into about 4 different files and re-names them (NAME1-0.jpg, NAME1-1.jpg, NAME2-0.jpg, NAME2-1.jpg...)

I want to make a .bat file that will run and delete all of the files that are not the *-0.jpg files.

So far the closest I have come is the line:

```
for %i in (*) do if not %i == "*.jpg" del "%i"
```

but this just goes and deletes all of the files in the folder including the -0.jpg's I want to save.

is there a better line to use?

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to delete all the files that are not the *-0.jpg files.

> I have a program that runs, and splits each file into about 4 different files and re-names them (NAME1-0.jpg, NAME1-1.jpg, NAME2-0.jpg, NAME2-1.jpg...)

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b NAME?-?.jpg') do (
  rem get file name
  set _fname=%%~ni
  rem get last 2 characters of file name
  set _last2=!_fname:~-2!
  if [!_last2!] NEQ [-0] del "%%i"
  )
```

Example:

```
F:\test>dir *.jpg
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

08/12/2015  23:51                 0 NAME1-0.jpg
08/12/2015  23:51                 0 NAME1-1.jpg
08/12/2015  23:51                 0 NAME2-0.jpg
08/12/2015  23:51                 0 NAME2-1.jpg
               4 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,776,919,613,440 bytes free

F:\test>test
F:\test>dir *.jpg
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

08/12/2015  23:51                 0 NAME1-0.jpg
08/12/2015  23:51                 0 NAME2-0.jpg
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,776,919,613,440 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.